# How to install a particular version of boost with brew on MacOSX?

Tags: command-line, macintosh

The command "brew install boost" works for me on my MacOSX, but it installs the latest boost 1.57. How to use brew to install the older 1.55?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to run `brew install boost@1.55`

```
$ brew search boost
==> Formulae
boost ✔                           boost-build                       
boost-python                      boost-python@1.59                 
boost@1.57                        boost@1.60 ✔
boost-bcp                         boost-mpi                     
boost-python3                     boost@1.55                        boost@1.59

==> Casks
boostnote                                focus-booster                            
iboostup                                 nosqlbooster-for-mongodb                 
turbo-boost-switcher
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to compile exact version manually from source.
Just do the following

1. Download the the .tar.gz of exact version from https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/native/main/release
2. Unpack and go into the directory:

   ```
   tar -xzf boost_1_50_0.tar.gz
   cd boost_1_50_0
   ```
3. Configure (and build `bjam`):

   ```
   ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0
   ```
4. Build:

   ```
   ./b2
   ```
5. Install:

   ```
   ./b2 install
   ```