# How do I install an older version of boost-python3 on Mac OS

Tags: macos, homebrew, boost

Currently,

```
brew install boost-python3
```

installs a new version of boost and the library boost_python38 (libboost_python38.dylib), however I need boost_python37 or older.

I managed to install an older version of boost and boost-python using

```
brew install boost@1.6
```

and

```
brew install boost-python@1.59
```

according to the answer given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189445/how-to-install-a-particular-version-of-boost-with-brew-on-macosx), but cannot find any way to do anything similar for boost-python3.